# Way to retrive hierarchical data from MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hierarchical-data

I am using Mongodb to store some data using Mongoose. I want to know if there is out of the box featrue to get hierarchical data:

Assume I have a document named `Books`. Books has a child name `Programming`. Programming have two children `Databases & Languages` & so on. See below image for more information on hierarchy.

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", children: [] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "dbm", children: [] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", children: [ "MongoDB", "dbm" ] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", children: [] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", children: [ "Databases", "Languages" ] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", children: [ "Programming" ] } )
```

[image]

**Is there any way to retrive hierarchical data using some out of the box feature in Moongose? I should be able to get output like this** .

```
{
    name: "books",
    nodes: [
        {
            name: "Programming",
            nodes: [
                {
                    name: "Databases",
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            name: "MonogoDB"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "dbm"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Languages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

So far I have tried this, but due to asyn nature of Mongoose, I am not able to generate desired result.

```
  //Find all top level documents. Currently I only have books as top level document
    //But in future there can be multiple top level doc. 
    //All top level doc will have parent as null
myDoc.find({
    parent: null
  }, function (err, topics) {
    if (err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    }
    var docTree = [];
    _.each(document, function(parentDoc) {
       var doc = {};
       doc.text = parentDoc.name;
      doc.nodes = [];
      _.each(parentDoc.children, function(child) {
        doc.nodes.push(processChildren(child));
      });
      docTree.push(doc);

    });



function processChildren(child) {

  myDoc.findById(child, function (err,item) {
    var doc = {};
    doc.name = item._doc.name;
    doc.nodes = [];
    if (item._doc.children === null) {
      return topic;
    } else {
      _.each(item._doc.children, function (chld) {
        processChildren(chld);
      });
    }
    return doc;
  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [embedded docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) you'll get the data just like that out of the box. But embedded docs have to be an array and they're not actually stored in their own collection in MongoDB (they're just a mongoose layer) so you're essentially just creating/storing one big document afa mongoDB is concerned.

Or you can use [referenced documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) and use plugins like [deep-populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) which will save you from manually looping to get the desired output.

Comment: Currently my scheme does not maintain any reference. Every document has an children array which contains document id's of its children.